# JMeter - Unable to click Parameter tab when added Body Data

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, web-api-testing, jmeter-4.0

Why I cannot click on Parameters tab in HTTP Request section after I insert JSON body data in Body Data tab? I tried to define correlation and of course this will require us to define the variable as well. Just wondering, after I'm done with correlation part, how can I insert the variable in Parameters if it is disabled?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't send Parameters and Body Data, you must choose only one option of sending request body

If you need to send extra parameters in additional to request body then use query parameters in Path field, for example

```
path?parameter1=value&parameter2=value2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to [variablize/correlate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) the JSON request body - you can put the relevant [JMeter Functions/Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) directly into "Body Data" tab

[image]

as you can see all the functions/variables are getting replaced by their respective values.

Also most probably you're getting JSON as the response so it makes sense to consider switching to [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or even better [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/) for the correlation.

Comment: What is the meaning of function u defined `${__jexl3(${__time(,)}/1000,)}`? This will return time in what unit?

Comment: It's combination of [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) which returns the current timestamp in milliseconds since beginning of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) to convert it into seconds. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept.

Comment: i can't click on the body data tab. how can I do this?